# Python web server error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a python based web server, but I am receiving this error message. I am still new to python, and not sure what I have done wrong! I am using http://blog.scphillips.com/posts/2012/12/a-simple-python-webserver/ as a reference.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "control.py", line 203, in <module>
  app = TetheredDriveApp()   File "control.py", line 77, in __init__
  match = re.match('GET /api\?action=(\d|[A-Z]+)\sHTTP/1', req)   File "/usr/lib/python3.2/re.py", line 156, in match
  return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string) TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

Here is my relevant code...

```
import socket
import re

def __init__(self):
  host = ''
  port = 61338
  sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  sock.bind((host, port))
  sock.listen(1)

  self.onConnect()

  while True:
      csock, caddr = sock.accept()
      req = csock.recv(1024)
      match = re.match('GET /api\?action=(\d|[A-Z]+)\sHTTP/1', req)
      motionChange = False
      if match:
          action = match.group(1)

          # KeyPress
          if action == 'PP':
            self.sendCommandASCII('128')

      else:
          csock.sendall("0")
      csock.close()
```

Comment: Please post a [Short, Self-contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/) so that we can run your code and easily fix the problem!

Comment: No need to apologize :) I'll have a look at your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I think is happening: when you receiving input from the buffer (in `req = csock.recv(1024) # get the request, 1kB max`), it's coming in the form of bytes. `re` needs a string. Try the line `req = str(req, encoding = 'utf-8')` before the line `match = re.match('GET /move\?a=(\d+)\sHTTP/1', req)`, and see how far that gets you. If that doesn't work, try using a different encoding than utf-8.

```
req = csock.recv(1024)
req = str(req, encoding='utf-8') # encoding may need to be changed
match = re.match('GET /api\?action=(\d|[A-Z]+)\sHTTP/1', req)
```